# Multi user LAN chat for Windows Server 2003 Terminal Server

Tags: windows, chat

couple of users are using one Windows Server 2003 Terminal Server via RDP.

We need a LAN chat program. Can you suggest us?

We used VyPress Chat before we moved to RDP. But it doesn't support
multi user working simultaneously.

We need only a chat for a LAN.

The must have feature is ability to send files too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any freeware to accomplish this.

So I decided to set up Jabber (XMPP) server.

It is supported by most of the IM clients (Pidgin, Miranda IM etc.)

Comment: What was the problem with VCM?

Comment: I am getting "Socket creation error" all the time when second, third users are coming via RDP to the same machine (using Terminal Services). So, I think it doesn't support multi user environments for  simultaneous working

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**VCM**](http://www.http-tunnel.com/html/solutions/messenger.asp), which I used to use at university before all the server-based IM programs started to appear.